# Bootstrap form-check puts checkbox on text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I try to use bootstrap `form-check` class for creating a checkbox. This is part of my code:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-section">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input id="checkbox1" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">
        VS-57KM-Z9M1-WC6B-SRXL
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success w-100" type="submit">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

where `.form-section` class is:

```
.form-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 120px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

But unfortunately, this is what happens when I enter the page...

[image: checkbox]

What is more interesting is that it happens only on Windows, on Mac everything works properly. On both systems I use Google Chrome. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Your code works fine for me on latest version of Bootstrap and Chrome on both Windows and Mac. http://jsfiddle.net/0mosk57r/

Comment: try ctrl + shif+ r

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, I still don't know what is going on, only solution for me was to use my own custom style.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, Check below.I suggest you to hard reload your browser and check your output again.If you are still getting same, then you must be either misplaced your code on windows or there are someother styles which can be overriding.

```css
  .form-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 120px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

 <form>
  <div class="form-section">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input id="checkbox1" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">
        VS-57KM-Z9M1-WC6B-SRXL
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success w-100" type="submit">Confirm</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, I still don't know what is going on, only solution for me was to use my own custom style.